Deprecated imperative apply of Flutter's Gradle plugins: Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'
I am trying to migrate the project to the new Plugin DSL syntax, explained here:
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply.
But I keep getting this error below.
I am confused as to why it keeps showing version 7.3.3 which has no reference in my code.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':gradle:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.3.3/gradle-7.3.3.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.3.3/gradle-7.3.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 775ms
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.1.1" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.0" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.10" apply false
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics" version "2.8.1" apply false
}

include ":app"

build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
    def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
    if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
        keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
    }
android {
   

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "de.groschopp.gromotorcontroller"
        minSdkVersion 21
        compileSdkVersion 35
        targetSdkVersion 35
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

gradle-wrapper.properties
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-all.zip

Flutter doctor and java -version
dusan@Dusans-MacBook-Pro gromoc_mobile % flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.3, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS and macOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.87.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
dusan@Dusans-MacBook-Pro gromoc_mobile % java -version
java version "19" 2022-09-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19+36-2238)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19+36-2238, mixed mode, sharing)


Can it be that you removed namespace, compileSdkVersion, and ndkVersion from the android space in app/build.gradle?

Your error message speaks about task :gradle:compileGroovy and configuration :gradle:compileClasspath.
That means you have a project called gradle or an included build called gradle. This is the build that is failing. Probably you have convention plugins in there that are built or so.
And there you have a dependency on AGP 7.3.3 which does not exist. As Google unluckly named their AGP artifact gradle it often happens that people confuse the AGP version with a Gradle version (there 7.3.3 exists), and my educated guess is, that this is also what happened here.
